# OBV Calculation

Tags: pine-script-v5, ta-lib, pandas-ta

`obv = cum(change(src) > 0 ? volume : change(src) < 0 ? -volume : 0*volume)`

`obv2 = cum(sign(change(src)) * volume )`

obv and obv2 return different results

ta.obv(df['close'], df['volume']) returns the same result as obv2

I will also need the return value of obv calculation with talib

[OBV calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGM7Z.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've added an OBV indicator to TradingView, opened it's sources and found

```
obv = ta.cum(math.sign(ta.change(src)) * volume)
```

Then I cloned the indicator and replaced this line with

```
obv = ta.cum(ta.change(src) > 0 ? volume : ta.change(src) < 0 ? -volume : 0*volume)
```

And added it as a second indicator. I've got a different results. But also I've got a warning:

> line 9: The function 'ta.change' should be called on each calculation
> for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the
> ternary operator or from the scope

So, I replaced the line with

```
c = ta.change(src)
obv = ta.cum(c > 0 ? volume : c < 0 ? -volume : 0*volume)
```

And got exactly the same results as original OBV!
So your code for obv is incorrect and you shall google for explanation of this warning. For example: [The function should be called on each calculation for consistency, console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509661/the-function-should-be-called-on-each-calculation-for-consistency-console-outpu)